# seccomp=unconfined for a container in a kubernetes pod? Or: changing default in docker 1.10?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm running kubernetes with docker 1.10 and I want to run a container with `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` . I understand from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20870 that seccomp in general is not supported by kubernetes yet, but are there any workarounds?

Do I just need to downgrade docker to 1.9 and lose the security profiles altogether, or is there another way to give my container the access it needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Seccomp is disabled by default](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/21790) in kubernetes v1.2 for docker v1.10+, so you should not have problems running container with unconfined policy.

Comment: Oh, that's bad, disabling it by default

Comment: Not as bad as breaking critical applications for the majority of unsuspecting people that [don't know anything about seccomp](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20870#issuecomment-206139495).